# what is wrong with this code?

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox, google-chrome, click

I have created a jquery click event to delete something from the xml file.The code is as follows:

```
$(".delete_engine").bind("click",function(){
    var del = $(this);
    var id = del.attr("id");
    var c = confirm("You sure want to delete this?");

    if(c)
    {
        /* $(this).next('.pclass').remove();
        $(this).prev('.rurl').remove();
        $(this).remove();*/
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/cPEP_UI/Engine_engine_delete",
            data: "eid="+id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                $('#light').html("<img src='loading.gif' alt='loading gif'/>");
                $('#light').css("display","block");
                $('#fade').css("display","block");
                if(data.update == "success"){
                    del.parent().next().remove();
                    del.parent().remove();
                    $('#light').html(data.message+" "+data.update);
                }
            },
            error:function(xhr,err){
                //alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                alert("readyState: "+xhr.readyState+"\nstatus: "+xhr.status);
                $('.error').html("responseText: "+xhr.responseText);
            }
        }); 
    }
});
```

But the thing is, its not working with google chrome, but working correctly with mozilla firefox. Any ideas as to why this is happening?! Is it because of cache!?

Comment: What's not working?  What's happening that shouldn't, or not happening that should?

Comment: Not to be too picky, but would you mind tabbing this bad boy back to the left margin a bit? :)

Comment: What is not happening: It is not deleting that particular item from xml file and not showing and error message of jquery ajax method too. But in mozilla, its deleting it properly ad showing that #light id div.

Comment: This page is on `http://localhost:8080` also, right?

Comment: yes, its http://localhost:8080

Answer (score 1):

Your culprit is probably here. I would check the JSON that you're getting back to see if it's returning the results you're expecting for a given ID.

```
if(data.update == "success"){
    del.parent().next().remove();
    del.parent().remove();
    $('#light').html(data.message+" "+data.update);
}
```

Also, you should check for Javascript errors. jQuery's AJAX API does very strict validation on JSON strings when the dataType is set to JSON. It can be rather unforgiving.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mike, I have checked it..and the JSON is working fine. And it is absolutely showing no erros in mozilla firebug too, and its working fine there.

Comment: I've seen Chrome misbehave where Firefox is fine in other places. Chrome can be schizophrenic at times.

Comment: so, is there any solution for this?! Shall I use some other method of jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I have had issues getting data back from a JSON object using jQuery in Chrome in the past.  My solution was to make sure that the JSON that is being parsed is strictly formed.  In particular, make sure that all keys and values are wrapped in double quotes.

Here is an example of a JSON object that worked in an app I am working on.

{   "db" : { "count" : "4",
                 "records" : {
                 "124" : ["124", "cooldood137", "43.1922532075705,-76.2615720447455"],
                 "345" : ["345", "jillchill9", "45.1922532075705,-78.2615720447455"],
                 "987" : ["987", "bobdabanka", "43.4922532075705,-76.1615720447455"],
                 "654" : ["654", "foobarlounge", "46.1922532075705,-79.2615720447455"],
                 "674" : ["674", "ohai!lolcat", "56.1922532075705,-69.2615720447455"]
                 }
                }
                }

Comment: I am using json.simple package for it.